# Work in electric potential

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy

I've read that if we want to move a charge in an electric field then we need a work of an external force to move it from a low potential energy to a high one , but then I read on another source that also a work can be done to translate it from a high potential energy to a low one . Now am lost ! Because I thought that such a work is only needed in the case of (from low to high) not from high to low since this one can occur in nature so don't need a work, so is it true for both or what?

Comment: Some texts may discuss the moving of a "charge" (which would be postive) and others might be talking about moving electrons (which are negative).  The work done is opposite between those two situations.

Comment: its all about sign convention and the type of charge (positive or negative). A +ve charge will be pushed from high potential to low potential in the field. If you take the work done by the field to be +ve then work done by an external force to bring it from low potential to high potential is -ve. Similarly, think for -ve charge.

Answer (score 1):

> if we want to move a charge in an electric field then we need a work of an external force to move it from a low potential energy to a high one

Not true. The electric field itself exerts a force to move the charge. Moving the charge from high to low *does require work* and this work is done by the electric field itself.

Any force that causes movement is doing work. $W=Fs$ ($F$ is force that pushes something a distance $s$). Natural or not. External over not.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to be clear what is doing work on what. In the diagram below, consider a charge starting at rest at A. We release it, and it accelerates down the potential gradient. Here, the field is doing work on the charge - it is accelerating it and therefore giving it kinetic energy. As a result, the charge will travel through the potential minimum at point B.

In this next phase of the motion, the charge is moving from a low potential to a high potential, and is doing work on the field. The kinetic energy it has is being transferred to the field in the form of potential energy of the system. Once the charge arrives at C, it has exhausted its kinetic energy and can no longer do any work on the field.

[image]

In this sequence of events, no external work is done on the system, and the total energy remains constant. We can contrast it with the case when the charge starts at rest at B, and an external force moves it to A. Now the external force has done work on the system. Or the charge starts at A, and moves slowly to B whilst experiencing some dragging force. Now, the system has done work on an external agent.

Two final points; first, the work done by a force $\mathbf{F}$ is $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{s}$, where $\mathbf{s}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ are vectors - that is, the component of the force acting along the direction of travel is the one doing work. If $\mathbf{s}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ are orthogonal, no work is done.

Second, the test charge in these situations is often an electron, which has a negative electric charge so experiences a potential which is "upside down" compared to a positive charge.